# updating the nested arrays in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I can't update array cards by api. I have doc board :

```
        {
"_id" : ObjectId("59e096a7622a3825ac24f343"),
"name" : "1",
"users" : [ 
    ObjectId("59cd114cea98d9326ca1c421")
],
"lists" : [ 
    {
        "list" : "1",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "2",
                "Author" : [ 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d", 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d", 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22e"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "3",
                "Author" : []
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "list" : "fea",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "card",
                "Author" : []
            }
        ]
    }
],
"__v" : 0 }
```

I create function which is sended variable object with:

```
cardsObj = {
  indeksCard : indeksCard,
  cards : cards,
  IdBoard: IdBoard
}
```

IdBoard is ID which Board i want update, cards it is array which I want only update, and indeksCard is numer position cards array in lists.

so cardsObj.cards it seems :

```
        {
            "name" : "3",
            "Author" : ["59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d"]
        }
```

Ok I send to API where I get in function :

```
router.post('/add/author', function (req, res, next) {
var query = 'lists.'+req.body.cardsObj.indeksCard+'.cards';

  Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.cardsObj.IdBoard },
    {
      $set: {
         query: req.body.cardsObj.cards,
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true
    },
    ((cards) => {
      res.send(cards)
    })
  )
});
```

Please to someone helped me, it is very important for me.
And problem is that this function Board.findOneAndUpdate does not update my array i think its fault query.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is taking your variable `query` as a property('query' as another field) in the `Board` collection schema. It is not able to evaluate the `query` variable to give you the array property that you want.

To allow MongoDB to evaluate the variable, you can use [] around your query variable. this is known as `ComputedPropertyName`, defined in ES6.

Try this :

```
Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.cardsObj.IdBoard },
    {
      $set: {
         [query]: req.body.cardsObj.cards,
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true
    },
    ((cards) => {
      res.send(cards)
    })
  )
});
```

Look [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) for detailed information on [ComputedPropertyName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer).